# How do I restore the default unity login screen after removing xubuntu?

Tags: unity, xubuntu, login

I have installed xubuntu on top of ubuntu on my system, and I tried it out, and I found out that I like unity a lot more than xfce. I have removed all (or all that I know) of the xubuntu packages, but I still have the xubuntu login screen. The xubuntu login screen looks a lot more like unity now, but it is not the default one. Here is a link to what the login screen looks like now: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx1V4cWJSkHHMFhodW1UbmoxbXNPTlpnUlczSEJDMlpEenhr

Any help is greatly appreciated :D